# Using Guard to write to a DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, guard

Has anyone used Guard to track files coming in, and reading them?

I'd like Guard to watch a directory for files added to it, then read them, and write the details to a MySQL DB.

I have Guard set up, and it watches the correct directory, but I dont know how to reference the file to read it.

In my Rails application I have this in the Guardfile:

```
guard 'rails' do
  watch(//) do |modified_files|
    puts "Modified files: #{modified_files}"
  end
end
```

When I add a file, it returns the object ID:

```
Modified files: #<Guard::Watcher::Pattern::MatchResult:0x007f8cadb3fe20>
```

How do you parse that object and view its attributes?  Like what if it were a document and I wanted to read it, how can I incorporate `File.open` with Guard?

Comment: You can call `to_a` on `modified_files` and you'll have array of file paths. Then you can open them and read them

Comment: I tried it, but maybe I'm not understanding this correctly.  If I did something like this `puts modified_files.to_a ` It should puts the array.  But its saying to_a  is an undefined method.

Comment: and if I add `.to_s`, it puts `#<Guard::Watcher::Pattern::MatchResult:0x007fabcf8fb588>`.  (the object ID I assume)